# Index page redirects to php page rather than database submission

Tags: php, submit

When I click submit on my index form it should submit to a database. This is not happening. After clicking submit I am redirected to a new url that has an address the same as my php page.
Here is my index code and my php code. They are in separate pages on aptana.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#Datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });

function submitfunction(){
    event.preventDefault();
var Operator =  $( "#Operator" ).val();
var Datepicker = $( "#Datepicker" ).val();
var Start_Cycle_Time =  $( "#Start_Cycle_Time" ).val();
var Start_Cycle_TotalizerValue = $( "#Start_Cycle_TotalizerValue" ).val();
var Receiving_Tank = $( "#Receiving_Tank" ).val();
var End_Cycle_Time = $( "#End_Cycle_Time" ).val();
var End_Cycle_TotalizerValue = $( "#End_Cycle_TotalizerValue" ).val();
var DE (PreCoat) = $( "#DE (PreCoat)" ).val();
var _600R (RemovesAcid) = $( "#_600R (RemovesAcid)" ).val();
var R60 (RemovesWaxes) = $( "#R60 (RemovesWaxes)" ).val();
var D60 (RemovesMoistureAndGlycerin) = $("#D60 (RemovesMoistureAndGlycerin)").val();
var Filter_Sock = $( "#Filter_Sock" ).val();

    alert("submit called");//this is an alert that pops up when the submit button is selected
    alert(Operator);//this is an alert that pops up after a start date is selected and shows after the submit button
    alert(Datedatepicker);//an alert for the end date that shows after the submit button
    alert(Start_Cycle_Time);//alert for project name
    alert(Start_Cycle_TotalizerValue);//alert for milestone description
    alert(Receiving_Tank);//alert for entered by.
    alert(End_Cycle_Time);
    alert(End_Cycle_TotalizerValue);
    alert(DE (PreCoat));
    alert(_600R (RemovesAcid));
    alert(R60 (RemovesWaxes));
    alert( D60 (RemovesMoistureAndGlycerin));
    alert(Filter_Sock);
        $.getJSON('bleaching_report.php',{
            Operator: Operator,
            Datedatepicker: Datepicker,
            Start_Cycle_Time: Start_Cycle_Time,
            Start_Cycle_TotalizerValue: Start_Cycle_TotalizerValue,
            Receiving_Tank: Receiving_Tank,
            End_Cycle_Time: End_Cycle_Time,
            End_Cycle_TotalizerValue: End_Cycle_TotalizerValue,
            DE (PreCoat): DE (PreCoat),
            _600R (RemovesAcid): _600R (RemovesAcid),
            R60 (RemovesWaxes): R60 (RemovesWaxes),
            D60 (RemovesMoistureAndGlycerin),
            Filter_Sock: Filter_Sock,


        },

        function(res,status){
            alert(status);
            alert(res.message);
        });
}


  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><bold><center>Bleaching Report</center></bold></h1>

 <form action="bleaching_report.php" method="get">
    Operator: <input type="text" id="Operator">&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    Date: <input tupe="text" id="Datepicker">&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br>
    Start_Cylce_Time: <input tupe= "text" id="Start_Cycle_Time">&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br>
    Start_Cycle_TotalizerValue: <input type= "text" id="Start_Cycle_TotalizerValue">&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br>
    Receiving_Tank: <input tupe= "text" id="Receiving_Tank">&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br>
    End_Cycle_Time: <input tupe= "text" id="End_Cycle_Time">&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br>
    End_Cycle_TotalizerValue: <input tupe= "text" id="End_Cycle_TotalizerValue">&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br>
    DE (PreCoat): <input tupe= "text" id="DE (PreCoat)">&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br>
    _600R (RemovesAcid): <input tupe= "text" id="_600R (RemovesAcid)">&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br>
    R60 (RemovesWaes): <input tupe= "text" id="R60 (RemovesWaxes)">&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br>
    D60 (RemovesMoistureAndGlycerin): <input tupe= "text" id="D60 (RemovesMoistureAndGlycerin)">&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br>
    Filter_Sock: <input tupe= "text" id="Filter_Sock">&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" onclick="submitfunction()">
</form>

</body>



</html>

<?php
$Operator = $_GET['Operator'];
$Date = $_GET['Date'];
$Start_Cycle_Time = $_GET['Start_Cycle_Time'];
$Start_Cycle_TotalizerValue = $_GET['Start_Cycle_TotalizerValue'];
$Receiving_Tank = $_GET['Receiving_Tank'];
$End_Cylce_Time = $_GET['End_Cycle_Time'];
$End_Cylce_TotalizerValue = $_GET['End_Cylce_TotalizerValue'];
$DE (PreCoat) = $_GET['DE (PreCoat)'];
$_600R (RemovesAcid) = $_GET['_600R (RemovesAcid)'];
$R60 (RemovesWaxes) = $_GET['R60 (RemovesWaxes)'];
$D60 (RemovesMoistureAndGlycerin) = $_GET['D60 (RemovesMoistureAndGlycerin)'];
$Filter_Socks = $_GET['Filter_Socks'];


$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","MySQLr00t","WRE_Plym");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {

  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

  }

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO bleaching_report (Operator, Date, Start_Cycle_Time, Start_Cycle_TotalizerValue, Receiving_Tank,
 End_Cycle_Time, End_Cylce_TotalizerValue, DE (PreCoat), _600R (RemovesAcid), R60 (RemovesWaxes), D60 (RemovesMoistureAndGlycerin), Filter_Socks)
VALUES ( '$Operator', '$Date', '$Start_Cycle_Time', '$Start_Cycle_TotalizerValue', '$Receiving_Tank', '$End_Cylce_Time', '$End_Cylce_TotalizerValue', '$DE (PreCoat)', 
'$_600R (RemovesAcid)', '$R60 (RemovesWaxes)', '$D60 (RemovesMoistureAndGlycerin)', '$Filter_Socks')");

mysqli_select_db($con, "WRE_Plym") or die(mysqli_error());
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `bleaching_report` ";
    $result = mysqli_query($sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['Operator']. "<br>";
    echo $row['Date']. "<br>";
    echo $row['Start_Cycle_Time']. "<br>";
    echo $row['Start_Cycle_TotalizerValue']. "<br>";
    echo $row['Receiving_Tank']. "<br>";
    echo $row['End_Cycle_Time']. "<br>";
    echo $row['End_Cylce_TotalizerValue']. "<br>";
    echo $row['DE (PreCoat)']. "<br>";
    echo $row['_600R (RemovesAcid)']. "<br>";
    echo $row['R60 (RemovesWaxes)']. "<br>";
    echo $row['D60 (RemovesMoistureAndGlycerin)']. "<br>";
    echo $row['Filter_Socks']. "<br>";

}



mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors.  First and foremost, you're not using the `name` property in your text boxes.  Without `name`ing your text boxes you won't be able to pull down items from your query string.

`Operator: <input type="text" name="Operator" id="Operator">&nbsp;&nbsp;  // Add "name"`

You're also mispelling "type" in various locations:

Update:  I've made some corrections to your code.  It looks like you've not tried to run this yet - or I suspect you'd have caught many of these syntax errors yourself.  Please test this before asking for more help!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#Datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });

function submitfunction(){
    event.preventDefault();
var Operator =  $( "#Operator" ).val();
var Datepicker = $( "#Datepicker" ).val();
var Start_Cycle_Time =  $( "#Start_Cycle_Time" ).val();
var Start_Cycle_TotalizerValue = $( "#Start_Cycle_TotalizerValue" ).val();
var Receiving_Tank = $( "#Receiving_Tank" ).val();
var End_Cycle_Time = $( "#End_Cycle_Time" ).val();
var End_Cycle_TotalizerValue = $( "#End_Cycle_TotalizerValue" ).val();
var DE (PreCoat) = $( "#DE (PreCoat)" ).val();
var _600R (RemovesAcid) = $( "#_600R (RemovesAcid)" ).val();
var R60 (RemovesWaxes) = $( "#R60 (RemovesWaxes)" ).val();
var D60 (RemovesMoistureAndGlycerin) = $("#D60 (RemovesMoistureAndGlycerin)").val();
var Filter_Sock = $( "#Filter_Sock" ).val();

    alert("submit called");//this is an alert that pops up when the submit button is selected
    alert(Operator);//this is an alert that pops up after a start date is selected and shows after the submit button
    alert(Datedatepicker);//an alert for the end date that shows after the submit button
    alert(Start_Cycle_Time);//alert for project name
    alert(Start_Cycle_TotalizerValue);//alert for milestone description
    alert(Receiving_Tank);//alert for entered by.
    alert(End_Cycle_Time);
    alert(End_Cycle_TotalizerValue);
    alert(DE (PreCoat));
    alert(_600R (RemovesAcid));
    alert(R60 (RemovesWaxes));
    alert( D60 (RemovesMoistureAndGlycerin));
    alert(Filter_Sock);
        $.getJSON('bleaching_report.php',{
            Operator: Operator,
            Datedatepicker: Datepicker,
            Start_Cycle_Time: Start_Cycle_Time,
            Start_Cycle_TotalizerValue: Start_Cycle_TotalizerValue,
            Receiving_Tank: Receiving_Tank,
            End_Cycle_Time: End_Cycle_Time,
            End_Cycle_TotalizerValue: End_Cycle_TotalizerValue,
            DE (PreCoat): DE (PreCoat),
            _600R (RemovesAcid): _600R (RemovesAcid),
            R60 (RemovesWaxes): R60 (RemovesWaxes),
            D60 (RemovesMoistureAndGlycerin),
            Filter_Sock: Filter_Sock,


        },

        function(res,status){
            alert(status);
            alert(res.message);
        });
}


  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><bold><center>Bleaching Report</center></bold></h1>

  #
  #  EDIT:  Added "name" property to each of your input boxes.
  #

 <form action="bleaching_report.php" method="get">
    Operator: <input type="text" name="Operator" id="Operator">&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    Date: <input type="text" name="Date" id="Datepicker">&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br>
    Start_Cylce_Time: <input type="text" name="Start_Cycle_Time" id="Start_Cycle_Time">&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br>
    Start_Cycle_TotalizerValue: <input type="text" name="Start_Cycle_TotalizerValue"  id="Start_Cycle_TotalizerValue">&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br>
    Receiving_Tank: <input type="text" name="Receiving_Tank"  id="Receiving_Tank">&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br>
    End_Cycle_Time: <input type= "text" name="End_Cycle_Time" id="End_Cycle_Time">&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br>
    End_Cycle_TotalizerValue: <input type="text" name="End_Cycle_Totalizer_Value"  id="End_Cycle_TotalizerValue">&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br>
    DE (PreCoat): <input type="text" name="DE_PRECOAT"  id="DE (PreCoat)">&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br>
    _600R (RemovesAcid): <input type="text" name="600R" id="_600R (RemovesAcid)">&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br>
    R60 (RemovesWaes): <input type="text" name="R60" id="R60 (RemovesWaxes)">&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br>
    D60 (RemovesMoistureAndGlycerin): <input type="text" name="D60" id="D60 (RemovesMoistureAndGlycerin)">&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br>
    Filter_Sock: <input type= "text" name="Filter_Socks" id="Filter_Sock">&nbsp;&nbsp;<br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" onclick="submitfunction()">
</form>

</body>



</html>

<?php

//
//  If we get the Operator variable, we can continue.
//

#
#   EDIT:  Added check for "OPERATOR".  The query won't run unless it's in the query string.
#   

if ($_GET['Operator'])
{

#
#   EDIT:  Updated your GET's to match the names of your input boxes.  Note that things like $_GET['R60 (RemovesWaxes)']
#          are not reliable ways of capturing data from query strings.

    $Operator = $_GET['Operator'];
    $Date = $_GET['Date'];
    $Start_Cycle_Time = $_GET['Start_Cycle_Time'];
    $Start_Cycle_TotalizerValue = $_GET['Start_Cycle_TotalizerValue'];
    $Receiving_Tank = $_GET['Receiving_Tank'];
    $End_Cylce_Time = $_GET['End_Cycle_Time'];
    $End_Cylce_TotalizerValue = $_GET['End_Cycle_TotalizerValue'];
    $DE_PRECOAT = $_GET['DE_PRECOAT'];
    $_600R (RemovesAcid) = $_GET['600R'];
    $R60 (RemovesWaxes) = $_GET['R60'];
    $D60 (RemovesMoistureAndGlycerin) = $_GET['D60'];
    $Filter_Socks = $_GET['Filter_Socks'];


    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","MySQLr00t","WRE_Plym");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {

      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();

      }

      #
      # EDIT: Added "if/else" to your MySQL failure block.  If your connection fails, why try to evaluate a MySQL query?
      #

      else
      {

        #
        #  TODO - You need to update your $row's to match what's actually in the database.
        #

            mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO bleaching_report (Operator, Date, Start_Cycle_Time, Start_Cycle_TotalizerValue, Receiving_Tank,
             End_Cycle_Time, End_Cylce_TotalizerValue, DE (PreCoat), _600R (RemovesAcid), R60 (RemovesWaxes), D60 (RemovesMoistureAndGlycerin), Filter_Socks)
            VALUES ( '$Operator', '$Date', '$Start_Cycle_Time', '$Start_Cycle_TotalizerValue', '$Receiving_Tank', '$End_Cylce_Time', '$End_Cylce_TotalizerValue', '$DE (PreCoat)', 
            '$_600R (RemovesAcid)', '$R60 (RemovesWaxes)', '$D60 (RemovesMoistureAndGlycerin)', '$Filter_Socks')");

            mysqli_select_db($con, "WRE_Plym") or die(mysqli_error());
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM `bleaching_report` ";
                $result = mysqli_query($sql);

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                echo $row['Operator']. "<br>";
                echo $row['Date']. "<br>";
                echo $row['Start_Cycle_Time']. "<br>";
                echo $row['Start_Cycle_TotalizerValue']. "<br>";
                echo $row['Receiving_Tank']. "<br>";
                echo $row['End_Cycle_Time']. "<br>";
                echo $row['End_Cylce_TotalizerValue']. "<br>";
                echo $row['DE (PreCoat)']. "<br>";
                echo $row['_600R (RemovesAcid)']. "<br>";
                echo $row['R60 (RemovesWaxes)']. "<br>";
                echo $row['D60 (RemovesMoistureAndGlycerin)']. "<br>";  //  Are you sure this is how it's stored in your DB?
                echo $row['Filter_Socks']. "<br>";

            }



            mysqli_close($con);

        }

}
?>
```

Comment: @Jmaes Binford I corrected all of my spelling mistakes and added names in the form. To add the if statement in the php code do I do it for each column or just for the first column?

Comment: Choose an element that MUST be provided for your code to run.  If `operator` is something you always expect, it will be fine.  Have you gotten any closer with your results?

Comment: No I am no closer than I was before. Do I put my sql connection inside the if statement or where?